# Multiplying two matrices by a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am multiplying two matrices by a vector using `loop`. Is it possible to do that without using `loop`?

Something like `D1=C.*(A.*B)` is not working.

Below sample of code

```
clear;
clc;
A=rand(5,5);
B=rand(5,5);
C=[0.1 0.3];
for ii=1:2
    D(:,:,ii)=A.*B.*C(ii);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this how to do it:

```
 D=bsxfun(@times,A.*B,permute(C,[3 1 2]))
```

Explanation: the trick is to change `C` from a row vector (say x-direction) to the 3rd dimension (or z-direction) using `permute`, which is as if you would have defined C differently:

```
C(:,:,1)=0.1;
C(:,:,2)=0.3;
```

Now, `bsxfun` is a compact way to do the for loop you wrote. that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much. According to this. We can do it also like.                           A=rand(5,5);
B=rand(5,5);
C=[0.1 0.3];
C1=reshape(C,[1,1,2]);                                                           D1=A.*B.*C1;

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with mostly matrix indexing:

```
clear;
clc;
A=rand(5,5);
B=rand(5,5);
C=[0.1 0.3];

% Get matrices to final size
A = A(:,:,ones(length(C),1)); % repeat into third dimension as many times as length(C)
B = B(:,:,ones(length(C),1)); % repeat into third dimension as many times as length(C)
C = C(ones(1,size(A,2)),:,ones(1,size(A,1))); % make it size size(A,2)xlength(C)xsize(A,1) 
C = permute(C,[3 1 2]); % change to correct order

D = A.*B.*C;
```

Or as one liner (faster,requires less memory and doesn't change input variables):

```
D = A(:,:,ones(length(C),1)).*B(:,:,ones(length(C),1)).*permute(C(ones(1,size(A,2)),:,ones(1,size(A,1))),[3 1 2]);
```

Still, i think for most matrices sizes `bsxfun` is  faster (and better readable). But solving stuff with indexing is a lot more fun :P